# Can I use Clojure multimethods only on Java classes?

Tags: clojure, multimethod

I am a bit confused about whether I can only use clojure multimethods on clojure structures represented by Java classes, or can I base multimethods to dispatch on structs or other properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very common to build multimethods that dispatch on the class of the first or only argument.  In this case the "class" may be a Java class, a record (defrecord generates a Java class), or even an internal Clojure type like ISeq.

You can also dispatch on an arbitrary function of the args passed to the function.  For example, you could compute a function and dispatch on a keyword if you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can dispatch multimethods on an *arbitrary* function of the arguments (that function gets passed in as the second argument to `defmulti`. http://clojure.org/multimethods provides more details.

Answer (score 2):

**You can make your multimethods dispatch on *any* function you choose.**